# sendKeys not working on textarea with area-label and getting element not interactable exception

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

Firstly apologies for such a bad title, kindly suggest a good title.

Here are the details on my issue that I am facing:

Website:
`https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lzidy3m70r`

Steps:

1. Click on + button on top left
2. Select images and upload any image
3. update values in fields center, width and height

Issue: Not able to interact with any of the text areas of center, width and height. Keep getting element to interactable exception

Here is the html
[image: As you can see there is no input tag for width field only 2 span shows 15 separately and textarea is also not interactable]

As you can see there is no input tag for width field only 2 span shows 15 separately and textarea is also not interactable

Here is my xpath to identify textarea or span:

```
//textarea[contains(@class,'dcg-smart-textarea') and text()='"+imageName+"']/parent::div/parent::div/following-sibling::div//span[@class='dcg-mq-textarea']/textarea

//textarea[contains(@class,'dcg-smart-textarea')]/parent::div/parent::div/following-sibling::div//span[@class='dcg-mq-root-block dcg-mq-editing-overflow-right']/span
```

I have tried a lot of ways like first clicking on the div and once cursor is available then trying to type or first click, then clear and then type but after click is successful the next step fails with exception element not interactable.

I am thinking javascriptexecutor is required to somehow handle this case but I am not very well aware with javascript and ways to handle such fields.

Can someone please help me solve this issue and be able to successfully enter values for center, width and height fields?

Comment: How are you uploading the image ?

Comment: Using sendkeys with input your file as images button is of input your file. So I am able to pass the whole file path to input.... driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']").sendKeys("<image file path>")

Comment: okay, Please see below !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need JavaScript executor for this case.

Using the below xpath

```
//div[text()='Center:']//following-sibling::div
```

You can locate all the web elements related to div fields for center, width and Hight.

Now to locate the first element I am using xpath indexing :

```
(//div[text()='Center:']//following-sibling::div)[1]
```

This will target the first the center field.

Also, we will have to clear the default value which is already present in that div, for that we have the loop.

**Code :**

```
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lzidy3m70r");
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement centerWebElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("(//div[text()='Center:']//following-sibling::div)[1]")));
    centerWebElement.click();
    for (int i = 0; i<=10 ; i++) {
        action.moveToElement(centerWebElement).sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE).build().perform();
        Thread.sleep(100);
        System.out.println("Clicked on delete for "+ i + " time");
    }
    new Actions(driver).moveToElement(centerWebElement).pause(2).sendKeys("2021, 2021").build().perform();
```

Same way, for first width

```
(//div[text()='Center:']//following-sibling::div)[3]
```

and for first height

```
(//div[text()='Center:']//following-sibling::div)[7]
```

should help you past the issue.

Comment: Thanks cruisepandey for the response I'll try once I get back to my laptop. Until then where you able to actually try it out if this solution works?

Comment: No I did not run the code, but `JavaScriptExecutor setAttribute` is only solution if send_keys are not working

Comment: I tried but still doesn't seem to work. I have provided the website can you be kind enough to try ones pls? I am desparately looking a solution please

Comment: See above, It is working in my local.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks a lot @cruisepandey